# Proving convergance of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to determine whether the series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{(-1)^kk +2}$ converges or disverges. Surely, it's not absolutely convergent. I tried using Dirichlet's test by multiplying numerator and denominator by $(-1)^k$. Then $|\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}{(-1)^k}| < 2$ and $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{k +2(-1)^k}=0$$ but the sequence above isn't monotonic so Dirichlet's test doesn't work. Do you have any other ideas how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(s_N)$ denote the sequence of partial sums. For each $N\ge1$ we have
$$s_{2N}=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac1{2j+2}+\sum_{j=1}^N\frac1{-(2j-1)+2}\\
=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{5}{2(j+1)(3-2j)}$$
which converges absolutely by comparison with $\sum\frac{C}{k^2}$ for some constant $C$. Now
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}s_{2N+1}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(s_{2N}-\frac1{2N-1}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}s_{2N},$$
so it follows that the series converges.

Comment: Nice answer. (Should the denominator in the last fraction be $2N-1$?)

Comment: Yep well spotted, I'll fix that now.